# Squared magnitude of the scattered field versus observation angle

Tags: matlab, channel, telecommunication

I am trying to generate the figures in the paper [Intelligent Reflecting Surfaces at Terahertz Bands: Channel Modeling and Analysis][1]. Figure 2 is as below.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

What I get from my code is as below.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The following is the code used.

```
% Intelligent reflecting surfaces at terahertz bands: channel modelling and
% analysis
% figure 2

close all
clear all
clc

% setting latex inerpreter
set(groot,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex'); 
set(groot,'DefaultTextFontname', 'CMU Serif');
set(groot,'DefaultAxesFontName', 'CMU Serif');
set(groot,'DefaultTextFontSize',14)
set(groot,'DefaultAxesFontSize',14)

% phi: azimuth angle, theta: polar angle
% t: transmitter, r: receiver
% d: distance from origin
theta_r = 0:.1:90;   % receiver polar angel
theta_t = 30;        % transmitter polar angle
phi_r = 60;          % receiver azimuth angle
% amplitude of electric (E-field) of the incident plane
amplitudeE_i_squared = 1;            
f = 300e9;          % carrier frequency
D_r = 4;            % distances measured from the (0,0)th IRS element to Rx
c = 3e8;            % velocity of light
lambda = c/f;       % wavelength

%% 1. lx = ly = lambda/2, eq. 9
L_x = lambda/2;     % size of reflecting element in x
L_y = lambda/2;     % size of reflecting element in y

X = ((pi*L_x)/lambda) * sind(theta_r) * cosd(phi_r);
Y = ((pi*L_y)/lambda) * ( (sind(theta_r) * sind(phi_r)) - sind(theta_t));

F = cosd(theta_t)^2 * ( (cosd(theta_r).^2 * cosd(phi_r)^2) + ...
    sind(phi_r)^2);

E_s_NormSquared_eq9 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda)^2 * ...
    (amplitudeE_i_squared/D_r^2) * F .* sinc(X).^2 .* sinc(Y).^2);

plot(theta_r,E_s_NormSquared_eq9,'b');
hold on

%% 2. lx = ly = lambda/2, eq. 10
E_s_NormSquared_eq10 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda)^2 * ...
    (amplitudeE_i_squared/D_r^2) * F);

plot(theta_r,E_s_NormSquared_eq10,'k-.');

%% 3. lx = ly = 5*lambda, eq. 9
L_x = 5*lambda;
L_y = 5*lambda;

% lambda = 2*lambda;

X = ((pi*L_x)/lambda) * sind(theta_r) * cosd(phi_r);
Y = ((pi*L_y)/lambda) * ( (sind(theta_r) * sind(phi_r)) - sind(theta_t));

F = cosd(theta_t)^2 * ( (cosd(theta_r).^2 * cosd(phi_r)^2) + ...
    sind(phi_r)^2);

E_s_NormSquared_eq9 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda)^2 * ...
    (amplitudeE_i_squared/D_r^2) * F .* ...
    sinc(X).^2 .* sinc(Y).^2);

% E_s_NormSquared_eq10 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda)^2 * ...
% (amplitudeE_i_squared/D_r^2) * F);

plot(theta_r,E_s_NormSquared_eq9,'r');
% plot(theta_r,E_s_NormSquared_eq10,'r');

xlabel('$\theta_r [degrees]$');
ylabel('$||E_s||^2 [dB]$');
hl = legend('$L_x = L_y = \lambda/2$ (Eq. 9)',...
    '$L_x = L_y = \lambda/2$ (Eq. 10)',...
    '$L_x = L_y = 5\lambda$');
set(hl, 'Interpreter','latex')
xlim([min(theta_r) max(theta_r)]);

% saveas(gca, ['f2_', datestr(now,'ddmmyyyy'), '.png']);
```

My plot and the z-axis range are not similar to the one in the paper.

Could you please point out the mistake I am doing. Thank you.

[1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15239#:~:text=Intelligent%20Reflecting%20Surfaces%20at%20Terahertz%20Bands%3A%20Channel%20Modeling%20and%20Analysis,-Konstantinos%20Dovelos%2C%20Stylianos&text=An%20intelligent%20reflecting%20surface%20(IRS,for%20the%20severe%20propagation%20losses.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3atos.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk004.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.- Cardinal sin or sinc has 2 definitions :**

While the obvious definition is `sinc(x)=sin(x)/x` in signal processing `sinc` is often defined as `sinc(x)=sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)`

Please understand that my main objective here was to get to the code producing the expected curves with certain coherence, but further refinement may be needed.

The following changes in the code supplied in the question bring all 3 graphs to the expected curves.

```
close all;clear all;clc

theta_r = [0:.1:90]; % [degree] receiver polar angle
theta_t =30;            % [degree] transmitter polar angle range
phi_r= 60;              % [degree] receiver azimuth angle range

% amplitude of electric (E-field) of the incident plane
Ei2 = 1;            
f = 300e9;              % [Hz]  carrier frequency
D_r = 4;                 % [m]  distances measured from the (0,0)th IRS element to Rx
c = 3e8;                  % [m/s] velocity of light
lambda = c/f;          % [m]  wavelength

%% 1. lx = ly = lambda/2, eq. 9
L_x = lambda/2;     % [m]  size of reflecting element in x 
L_y = lambda/2;     % [m] size of reflecting element in y

X = pi*((pi*L_x)/lambda) * sind(theta_r) * cosd(phi_r);
Y = pi*((pi*L_y)/lambda) * ( (sind(theta_r) * sind(phi_r)) - sind(theta_t));

F = cosd(theta_t)^2 * ( (cosd(theta_r).^2 * cosd(phi_r)^2) + sind(phi_r)^2);

Es2_eq9 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda^2)^2 * (Ei2/D_r^2) * F .*sinc(X).^2 .* sinc(Y).^2*1/pi^4);

plot(theta_r,Es2_eq9,'b');
hold on
axis([0 90 -140 -40])

%% 2. Lx = Ly = lambda/2, eq. 10
Es2_eq10 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda)^2 * (Ei2/D_r^2) * abs(F));

plot(theta_r,Es2_eq10,'k-.');

%% 3. Lx = Ly = 5*lambda, eq. 9
N=50
L_x = lambda/N;
L_y = lambda/N;

X = pi*((pi*L_x)/lambda) * sind(theta_r) * cosd(phi_r);
Y = pi*((pi*L_y)/lambda) * ( (sind(theta_r) * sind(phi_r)) - sind(theta_t));

F = cosd(theta_t)^2 * ( (cosd(theta_r).^2 * cosd(phi_r)^2) + sind(phi_r)^2);

Es2_eq9_2 = 10*log10(N*((L_x*L_y)/lambda^2)^2 * (Ei2/D_r^2) * F .* sinc(X).^2 .* sinc(Y).^21/pi^4);

plot(theta_r,Es2_eq9_2,'r');
grid on; grid minor;

xlabel('theta_r (degree)');ylabel('|E_s|^2 (dB)');

legend({'L_x = L_y = \lambda/2 (Eq. 9)',...
                  'L_x = L_y = \lambda/2 (Eq. 10)',...
                  ['L_x = L_y = lambda /' num2str(N) ]}, ...
                  'Location','northeast');
```

[image]

**2.- X and Y modifyed**

Heading `pi` to comply with `sinc` definition **sinc(x)=sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)**

A factor `1/pi^4` is added when calculating |Es2| in dB, again tot satisfy the `sinc` definition including pi.

If you would like to know why in signal processing `sinc(x)=sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)` please post another question.

**3.- Electric field  have to be [V/m]**

Otherwise it's electric field no more.

Yet as defined in the paper, right after **Figure.2**

[image]

The units of `Es` are not `[V/m]` but `[V/m^3]`

May be the opening factor `(Lx*Ly/lambda)` should be `(Lx*Ly/lambda^2)` .

However it's more probable that the opening `Lx` `Ly` factor should be `((Lx/lambda)*(Ly/lambda)/lambda)`.

**This squares electric field units to** `[V/m]` .

**5.- 3rd curve in paper may be wrong**

When `Lx` `Ly` both rise to `5*lambda` the resulting `abs(Es(theta_r))` cannot remain as smooth as as compared to when `Lx` `Ly` a fraction of lambda.

The red graph in the paper seems closer to `Lx` `Ly` containing a fraction of `lambda` rather than several `lambda`.

So perhaps for the 3rd curve, either the 3rd graph in the paper Figure.2 is not correct, or instead of `Lx=5*lambda` `Ly=5*lambda` it should be `Lx=lambda/50` `Ly=lambda/50` then meeting **Lx>>lambda** and **Ly>>lambda**.

Consider that the 3rd curve on Figure.2 may not be correct.

```
close all;clear all;clc

theta_r = [0:.1:90]; % [degree] receiver polar angle
theta_t =30;            % [degree] transmitter polar angle range
phi_r= 60;              % [degree] receiver azimuth angle range

% amplitude of electric (E-field) of the incident plane
Ei2 = 1;            
f = 300e9;              % [Hz]  carrier frequency
D_r = 4;                 % [m]  distances measured from the (0,0)th IRS element to Rx
c = 3e8;                  % [m/s] velocity of light
lambda = c/f;          % [m]  wavelength

% 1. lx = ly = lambda/2, eq.9
L_x = lambda/2;     % [m]  size of reflecting element in x 
L_y = lambda/2;     % [m] size of reflecting element in y

X = pi*((pi*L_x)/lambda) * sind(theta_r) * cosd(phi_r);
Y = pi*((pi*L_y)/lambda) * ( (sind(theta_r) * sind(phi_r)) - sind(theta_t));

F = cosd(theta_t)^2 * ( (cosd(theta_r).^2 * cosd(phi_r)^2) + sind(phi_r)^2);

Es2_eq9 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda^2)^2 * (Ei2/D_r^2) * F .*sinc(X).^2 .* sinc(Y).^2*1/pi^4);

plot(theta_r,Es2_eq9,'b');
hold on; grid on
axis([0 90 -140 -40])

% 2. Lx = Ly = lambda/2 , eq.10
Es2_eq10 = 10*log10( ((L_x*L_y)/lambda)^2 * (Ei2/D_r^2) * abs(F));

plot(theta_r,Es2_eq10,'k-.');

% 3. Lx = Ly = 5*lambda , eq.10
N=1/5
L_x = lambda/N;
L_y = lambda/N;

X = pi*((pi*L_x)/lambda) * sind(theta_r) * cosd(phi_r);
Y = pi*((pi*L_y)/lambda) * ( (sind(theta_r) * sind(phi_r)) - sind(theta_t));

F = cosd(theta_t)^2 * ( (cosd(theta_r).^2 * cosd(phi_r)^2) + sind(phi_r)^2);

Es2_eq9_2 = 10*log10(N*((abs(L_x*L_y)/lambda^2)^2 * (Ei2/D_r^2) * F .* sinc(X).^2 .* sinc(Y).^2*1/pi^4));

plot(theta_r,Es2_eq9_2,'r');

xlabel('theta_r (degree)');ylabel('|E_s|^2 (dB)');

legend({'L_x = L_y = \lambda/2 (Eq. 9)',...
            'L_x = L_y = \lambda/2 (Eq. 10)',...
            ['L_x = L_y =' num2str(1/N) ' lambda' ]}, ...
            'Location','northeast');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. It really helped me a lot.

Comment: Hello @John BG, Could you please check figure 3 as well? This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75636354/path-loss-across-an-100100-element-irs.